# On the equivalence of the two definitions of Hadamard differentiability

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Sorry if this question is not eligible. I have posted it on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629943/existence-of-a-continuously-differentiable-function-with-prescribed-properties), but hasn't received any responses.

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff locally convex space. As it is known [e.g., see Yamamuro S. (1974). Differential Calculus in Topological Linear Spaces. Springer-Verlag. P. 9], the following two definitions of Hadamard differentiability of a function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ at a point $c$ are equivalent.

(1) There is a continuous linear functional $A \in L(X,\mathbb R)$ such that for any convergent sequence $t_n \rightarrow 0$ of positive real numbers and a convergent sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$, $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac {f(c+t_nx_n)-f(c)} {t_n} = A(x)$.

(2) There is a continuous linear functional $A \in L(X,\mathbb R)$ such that for any continuous function $g:\mathbb R \to X$ such that $g(0)=c$ and the derivative $g'(0)$ exists, the function $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $(f \circ g)'(0)=A(g'(0))$.

Averbukh & Smolyanov [Averbukh V.I., Smolyanov O.G. (1968). The various definitions of the derivative in linear topological spaces // Russian Math. Surveys 23:4. P.67–113. Theorem 3.2, 3.3]
showed that the condition of continuity of $g$ in (2) can be strengthened to differentiablility without changing the result.

I wonder can differentiablility of $g$ be further strengthened to continuous differentiablility without changing the result?

Put differently, the question can be stated as follows. Given a sequence $t_n \rightarrow 0$ of pairwise distinct positive real numbers and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$, is there a continuously differentiable function $g:\mathbb R \to X$ such that $g(t_n)=t_nx_n$ and $g'(0)=x$?

Thank you.